# how to add text in local file with javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to add the line `<script src="test.js"></script>` after the line `<script src="original.js"></script>` in an existing .html-file with JavaScript.

All files are local (not on a webserver) but I have no clue how to do this. It would be very nice if someone would push me into the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, don't think it's possible to edit a .html-file with JavaScript alone. You would need something like a server-side language like PHP.

Comment: You need server side code to handle writing files. JavaScript on the client doesn't have permissions to write to a file by itself.

Comment: Is this by chance a node.js-related question?

Comment: you're not asking how to just edit an .html file are you? You can do that with any text-editor. Manipulating file contents with JavaScript is not possible with normal "client-side" JavaScript, but you can inject a <script> on the fly like in [@Cameron's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23615259/363701). What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

On the client, you can inject the `<script>` element into the DOM after the DOM has loaded like this:

```
(function(d, script) {
    script = d.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = function(){
        // remote script has loaded
    };
    script.src = 'test.js';
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}(document));
```

However, file manipulation needs to be done server side with a language like PHP, Ruby, C#, etc.